# Converting a word into a number in android and doing the opposite action in JSP

Tags: android, jsp

I am trying to pass a word (for example: laptop) from android to JSP. I want to convert the word in to a value and sent it in to the JSP(I am able to send numbers from android to JSP as parameters) and once the value is received at the server side (i.e JSP) i need to convert that number back in to that original word. All i need to know is that, is there any way for converting a word to a value and convert it back from that value?

Comment: Is the conversion really necessary? Why don't you just send the word as request parameter to JSP?

Comment: @BalusC : Actually i was expecting this question. Sir, actually i am facing a problem in that. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174881/difficulty-in-passing-text-as-parameter-from-android-to-jsp-page/8175385#8175385

Comment: @BalusC: So the alternative that I found is passing values instead of text as values works fine. So i need to know this.

Comment: All I can suggest is to contact your tutor and ask what that webservice really expects. This is not normal.

Comment: @BalusC: So we can't create a function for converting a word to a value(at least by assigning some constant value for each letter)?
I know it is not a correct solution, but i can at least use this as a temporary solution.

Comment: You can, but that's merely a workaround. Since this is homework, you really need to contact your tutor or you may lose points for not using the normal ways of communicating with the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use base36 encoding, by using for example the java.math.BigInteger package.

The following example shows that 2969070082552543387862 is the base 36 equivalent of "helloworldaz12".

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("2969070082552543387862").toString(36));
System.out.println(new BigInteger("helloworldaz12", 36));
```